# Android using AsyncTask to update the UI

Tags: android-asynctask, android

I want to know when the asynctask is finished, such that I could update the UI.

Can anybody help???? thanks!!!

```
public String[] getinfo(int id) {


    String[] QueueNo = null;

    try {           
        new DLfromServer().execute("url link"); // this is the asynctask

        // want to do stuff here after the asynctask is completed
                    // actually I want to return a string result after the task is finished....

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("GetJSON", "Err:", e);
    }

    return QueueNo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to know when the asynctask is finished, such that I could update
>   the UI.

Yes, you can use `onPostExecute` method which call on UI Thread after `doInBackground` execution is completed.

if you want to get data back on Main UI Thread then use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method for executing AsyncTask because this method make wait on UI Thread until `doInBackground` execution is completed .

```
    String str_result= new DLfromServer().execute("url link").get();
    // now use str_result for Updating result
```

**NOTE :-** you will need to call `AsyncTask.get()` inside an Thread instead of Main UI Thread otherwise calling of get() method will freeze Main Thread until `doInBackground` execution is complete

Comment: Can you give example on how to call AsyncTask.get() inside an Thread? Asynctask is actually a class, and I'm calling it from a fragment... Does that already mean it's not on the main thread?

Comment: @user1702061 : simply create an Thread like in java and move `String str_result= new DLfromServer().execute("url link").get();` inside run method of Thread.